# how to retrieve spesific value on local storage with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

can someone help me to get spesific value of the local storage (ex: "name" : "budi" and "name" : "andrew"), i just only get the "andrew" name

```
aa = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("a"))
//$('#isinama').text('Welcome ' + aa)

var data_user1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data_user'))

for (var i in data_user1) {
  var entry = data_user1[i]
}

if (aa == entry.username) {
  $.each(entry2, function(i, data) {
    $('#listcurhat').append('<div class="card mb-3" style="max-width:24rem;"><div class="card-header" id="isinama2">' + aa + '</div><div class="card-body"><p class="card-text">' + data.textcurhat + '</p></div></div>')
  })
}
```

in this condition, 'aa' have a spesific value because i was looping and return value above on it, can help spesific value for 'entry.username' cause i have many username on data_user localstorage

[image]

example of my localstorage

Comment: Put the code that uses `entry` inside the `for` loop. Otherwise you're just using the last one.

Comment: ok sir, but if i want get spesific value username of third index "udin", what should i do?

Comment: i wanna try if (aa == (spesific value) ){}

Comment: See the linked question, it says how to find an object in an array with a specific value of a property.

Comment: Or you can just put that `if` statement into the `for` loop.